# Creating a many-to-many join table where FK's might be duplicated, but payload information will always ensure uniqueness

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design

Consider the following Many-to-Many join table with relevant payload information:

| (Key) FK_File_ID | (Key) FK_Status_ID | DateTime |

My problem is that a given file may be put into a specific status multiple times. throughout its lifetime.  However, it could never be in that same status at the same time; Datetime will always ensure that the two entries are unique.

My problem is that I can't set DateTime as a key, because I need to be able to update it if a user made a mistake on the time that file was put into that status.  (Currently, the client program, which I don't have control of, has the user select the time that a file was placed into that status).  I'm using Entity Framework, which would not let me update that date column if it were marked as a key.

In this case, should I give the join table it's own `ID` column?  I don't know if there are ramifications for doing it like that.  If it has it's own `ID` column, I suppose that means that the Primary key no longer needs to be composite, and can simply use the `ID` column as it's primary key now?

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you need to add another attribute to a join table then it is no longer just a join table, and you need an entity.

In this example the natural key is a composite of all 3 columns. But creating foreign keys to a composite key is more difficult, especially if you have to update the primary key as you do here.

I would add an ID field as the primary key and add a unique index on the natural key.

Comment: Ah, adding a unique index to the natural key is a fantastic idea.  that makes me feel a lot better about it.  Thanks!